# Sequential definition of continuity of $f$ at $x$ is equivalent ...

Tags: analysis

Prove that the Sequential definition of continuity of $f$ at $x$ is equivalent to the $\epsilon,\delta"$ definition, which is

for any $\epsilon$ > 0,

for some $\delta$ >0

for all $u$ $[||x-u|| < \delta  =>  ||f(x)-f(u)||<\epsilon]$

How to prove that? in word equivalent means we must prove if and only if right?

thank you .

Comment: You can find tons of results on Google just by typing "Sequential definition of continuity". Moreover, this has been posted several times here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous function. So given, given $x\in \mathbb{D}_f$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ implies $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. If $x_n\to x$ then there is $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>n_0$ implies $|x_n-x|< \delta$, therefore $|f(x_n)-f(x)|< \epsilon$, i.e., $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$.

Try to prove the conversely.